# Displaying the Image for Cards in a Poker Game

Tags: java, object, png

so I'm supposed to create accessor methods getSuit and getValue for the mySuit and myValue fields, respectively. Then I also need to make a method imageFileName that returns the filename of the image that will be used when I display the card in a graphics window.

The filenames are strings that use only numbers, lower case letters, underscore characters, and a period. They all end in ".png". Here are some examples:

```
"2_of_diamonds.png" 
"10_of_clubs.png"
"ace_of_spades.png"
"queen_of_hearts.png"
```

**Card Class**

```
public class Card 
{ 
  /** This card's suit */ 
  private String mySuit; 
  /** This card's pip value (aces high) */ 
  private int myValue; 
  /** The English names of the cards in a suit */ 
  private String[] cardNames =  
      { 
        "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
      }; 

  /** 
   * The class constructor 
   * 
   * @param suit   A String, either "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", or "clubs" 
   * @param value  An int from 2 through 14 
   */ 
  public Card( String suit, int value ) 
  { 
    mySuit = suit; 
    myValue = value; 
  } 

  /** 
   * Gets the full English name of this card 
   * 
   * @return the full name of this card in English 
   */ 
  public String name() 
  { 
    return cardNames[ myValue - 2 ] + " of " + mySuit; 
  } 


public String getSuit()
{
    return this.suit;
}
public int getValue()
{
    return this.value; 
﻿}

/**
 * Gets the filename of this card's image
 *
 * @return the filename of this card's image
 */
public String imageFileName()
{
 return ???.toLowerCase(); // This is the part I'm stuck on

}
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  Card c = new Card( "diamonds", 10 );
  System.out.println( "Value: " + c.getValue() );
  System.out.println( "Suit: " + c.getSuit() );
  System.out.println( "Filename: " + c.imageFileName() );
}
```

and the expected result is:

Value: 10

Suit: diamonds

Filename: 10_of_diamonds.png

If somebody could please explain what to use in the imageFileName method, I'd be very grateful.  Thank you!

Comment: You could work out the logic of how to solve this with pencil and paper, I would guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the strings, adding underscores and "of"s? Have a look at the [Java String tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html), search for "java string concatenation" on the web and here on SO.

To give you some code to play with as  well:

```
return myValue + "_of_" + mySuit.toLowerCase() + ".png";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and thanks for the link as well, I just finished reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return myValue + "_of_" + mySuit.toLowerCase();
```

(actually if the suit is always lowercase like your "diamonds", you don't need the `.toLowerCase()` at all)